# Get cell value from structured table with [header] as String?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table called tblPlayerList which has Player names in Column A [Name], and their points in columns called [WK01] to [WK45] like this:

```
NAME             POS    CLUB    WK01    WK02    WK03
David Ospina      GK    Arsenal   12        
Emiliano Martinez GK    Arsenal         
Petr Cech         GK    Arsenal         
Wojciech Szczesny GK    Arsenal         
Calum Chambers   DEF    Arsenal         
Gabriel Paulista DEF    Arsenal         
Héctor Bellerín  DEF    Arsenal         
Isaac Hayden     DEF    Arsenal
```

I have Matched the Row number for a player, and have the week number stored as a String "WK01" which I deliberately converted into that format for the purpose of referencing the column headers, but can't get it to work.

How can I get the points from, say, WK01 for a player, say, on Row 1?

```
Dim RowNum, GetPoints As Integer
Dim ColumnName As String

RowNum = 1
ColumnName = "WK01"

GetPoints = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just assume that the table ListObject (aka *structured table*) is named Table1 on Sheet1.

```
Dim GetPoints As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")    'set this worksheet reference properly
    GetPoints = Application.Index(.Range("Table1"), _
                  Application.Match("David Ospina", .Range("Table1[NAME]"), 0), _
                  Application.Match("WK01", .Range("Table1[#Headers]"), 0))
End With
```

You can replace the hard-coded strings in my example with assigned string vars.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! Just for info, I did actually give you the name of the table in the first sentence of my question - it's tblPlayerList, but I admit to not saying what the sheet was called ("PLAYER LIST"). I'll give this a go now.

Comment: That worked brilliantly, thanks!
Now I just need to add their new points to GetPoints, and put the new total back in the cell it came from...

Comment: I just swapped your code around to add the total back into the Matched cell in the table and it works perfect!
Thanks very much Jeeped :)